# PyQt5 QInputDialog not showing

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am playing around with extending the QInputDialog, which I want to open when the user presses a certain shortcut. I can see the shortcut run and the code runs correctly past the `show()` method but the QInputDialog is never shown.

This only happens when I try to open the QInputDialog through a shortcut, if I just put the QInputDialog in my main method, it runs fine.

```
class CommandPopup(QInputDialog):
""" popup for a single-line command to be entered"""
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupGUI()
    self.command_runner = commands.CommandRunner()

def setupGUI(self):
    self.setLabelText("Command:")
    self.show()

def done(self, result):
    super().done(result)
    print("done")
    if result == 1:
        print(self.textValue())
        self.command_runner.run(self.textValue())
```

This works when I put this in my main function

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = CommandPopup()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But when I try to call the code from another function on a shortcut, it does not show the input dialog.

```
         self.textArea.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("CTRL+E"),self)
         self.textArea.shortcut.activated.connect(self.command_popup)
```

with:

```
 def command_popup(self):
    x = CommandPopup()
```

(SO messed up the indentation a bit, but the indentation is correct, I can see string output if I print something after the `self.show()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must pass a `parent` to the object. To do this we must modify the constructor by adding that parameter.

```
class CommandPopup(QInputDialog):
    """ popup for a single-line command to be entered"""
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        [...]
```

---

```
def command_popup(self):
    print("print")
    command = CommandPopup(self)
```